# OutOfMemory exception when converting object to Json through Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson, savestate

i am getting

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

for some users (not always) when I convert a list of object to JSON using Gson. please tell me how to fix that.

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if(myList != null && !myList.isEmpty()) {
            //exception at this line
            String myJson = new Gson().toJson(myList, myList.getClass());
            outState.putString(MY_LIST, myJson);
        }
        outState.putInt(NEXT_PAGE, getNextPage());
    }
```

myList is the list of my custom object and size of list is 400kb to 600kb

Comment: check the size of that myList

Comment: @Stultuske  it's size is large. but i have to convert large sized list. is there any way?

Comment: Is `myList` a regular List? What is the class of objects contained in `myList`?

Comment: @HeikkiMäenpää it's list of my custom object
and size of list is 400kb to 600kb

Comment: Can you convert a single object to JSON without any trouble? I have seen JSON serialization get stuck in a recursion when one object has a member of a type that has a reference to the object it's a member of.

Comment: yes i can convert a single object to JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on the size of your list. Why don't you use streaming API https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming

To be more specific something like

```
public String writeListToJson(List myList) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream =new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(byteStream ,"UTF-8");
    JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(outputStreamWriter);
    writer.setIndent("  ");
    writer.beginArray();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    for (Object o : myList) {
        gson.toJson(o, o.class, writer);
    }
    writer.endArray();
    writer.close();
    return byteStream.toString("UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: why would you use streaming `JsonWriter` if you are converting the final result to `String`?

Comment: @pskink if you see OP, he is writing back the "string" to outState `outState.putString(MY_LIST, myJson);`  It's the Gson converter that is not converting the big List in one go and hence a helper for gson. So he can use this util class, get past OOM from Gson and use the string as he wants it.

Comment: ok so in your method there is 1) big `myList` 2) big `ByteArrayOutputStream` which has to store `myList` content and 3) big `String` as the result of `byteStream.toString` the question is how those 3 big data objects would help in case of `OOM` exception?

Comment: He already had a big myList, Storing it in Stream is not an issue, its the conversion of big list in json string using Gson is cause of OOM. Not holding of these objects

Answer (score 1):

> myList is the list of my custom object and size of list is 400kb to 600kb

Do **NOT** put that in the saved instance state `Bundle`. `OutOfMemoryError` is only one of your worries. You will crash with a `FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION` much of the time, as there is a 1MB limit on all simultaneous IPC transactions going on in your app.

If you are trying to deal with configuration changes, use something else to hold onto this information:

- Retained fragment
- `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`
- `ViewModel` from the Android Architecture Components
- etc.

If you are trying to deal with process termination/app restart, put an identifier in the saved instance state `Bundle` that will allow you to reload this list from a persistent store (database, plain file, etc.).